# Mapping a jpa relationship where the attribute is of the same type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a class called person, that maps to a person table. A person has a collection of person objects as an attribute, that represent their children, and a collection of person objects that represent their parents.

Their is a link table that holds child/parent relationships by their ids. Here is what I have:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "id")
@JoinTable(name = "PARENT_TO_CHILD_LINK_TABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"))
private List<Person> parents;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "id")
@JoinTable(name = "PARENT_TO_CHILD_LINK_TABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"))
private ArrayList<Person> children;
```

I am getting an error saying that annotations marked as mapped by should not have `@JoinColumn` or `@JoinTable` annotations.

Does this relationship seem like a manytomany?

Comment: For starters, you want `@ManyToMany`. You can't have a relationship that's `@OneToMany` in both directions!

Comment: So when I make the relationship many to many, the mapped by goes away right?

Comment: You need it on one side. This is, for once, laid out very clearly in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html): "Every many-to-many association has two sides, the owning side and the non-owning, or inverse, side. The join table is specified on the owning side. If the association is bidirectional, either side may be designated as the owning side. If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of the ManyToMany annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.".

Comment: But is this considered a special case because the attribute is of the same type as the class/entity? I'm not sure what the mapped by property would be

Comment: No, it's not a special case. It's time i made this an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map a relationship where there is a collection at both ends, like the parent-child relationship, you want [`@ManyToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html). You can't have a relationship that's `@OneToMany` in both directions!

With `@ManyToMany`, you can have `@JoinTable` only on one side, and you need `mappedBy` only on the other side. This is, for once, laid out very clearly in the javadoc‌​:

> Every many-to-many association has two sides, the owning side and the non-owning, or inverse, side. The join table is specified on the owning side. If the association is bidirectional, either side may be designated as the owning side. If the relationship is bidirectional, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of the ManyToMany annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the owning side.

Remember that `mappedBy` *always* refers to a property in the entity at the other end of the relationship. In the case of a relationship between instances of the same entity, it refers to a property in the same entity that declares it. That may seem odd, but it's an application of the normal rule.

Here's some code that will work for you:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "PARENT_TO_CHILD_LINK_TABLE",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID"))
private List<Person> children;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "children")
private List<Person> parents;
```

You don't actually need the `@JoinTable` annotation; if you leave it out, the JPA provider will generate default names for the table and columns.

Comment: I have db system where must create tables beforehand not let JPA touch schema. How is createtable.sql for this use case, can you please edit answer showing example table structure and foreign keys?

Comment: Ah, in that case, you will almost certainly need a `@JoinTable` annotation. If you want to see what SQL is produced with and without the annotation, the best thing to do is to try it yourself - change your code, generate the SQL locally, and compare it to what you need.